# Is it possible to make Eclipse ignore syntax checking/formatting for one specific file?

Tags: eclipse, syntax, format, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Eclipse as an IDE for Ruby/Rails development (using Aptana plugin). I have one very, very large file that encompasses an initial data load of several thousand rows of data. When this file is open, everything grinds to a halt (on both Windows and Linux), presumably because Eclipse is tied up trying to parse and format/syntax-check the file. Typing in a single word takes upwards of a minute to complete.

Is there a way for me flag this file in such a way that Eclipse will skip it for format/syntax checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Navigator, right-click on the file and selecting Open With -> Text Editor. This will cause the file to be opened as plain text every time it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put all your files except the large one into a [working set](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2005/06/19/organizing-eclipse-projects-with-working-sets/), and then make that working set the default one.